# How To Change The $tid to $term_name

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, theming

I've tried to change this code to show the term name instead of the term ID
but now no term name or term id show at all

Orginal code for term ID

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {   if (array_key_exists('content', $vars)) {
    $content = &$vars['content'];
      if (array_key_exists('field_photo_topic', $content)) {
        foreach ($content['field_photo_topic']['#items'] as $index => $info) {
          $tid = $info['tid'];
          $content['field_photo_topic'][$index]['#href'] = 'photos/' . $tid;
        }
      }   } }
```

What I changed it too

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {   if (array_key_exists('content', $vars)) {
    $content = &$vars['content'];
      if (array_key_exists('field_photo_topic', $content)) {
        foreach ($content['field_photo_topic']['#items'] as $index => $info) {
          $term_name = $info['term_name'];
          $content['field_photo_topic'][$index]['#href'] = 'photos/' . $term_name;
        }
      }   } }
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get/modify taxonomy term info in node edit form field?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28177/get-modify-taxonomy-term-info-in-node-edit-form-field)

Answer (score 3):

To convert from `$tid` to term name, use  [`taxonomy_term_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7) to load the object, and then access `$term->name`:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$term_name = $term->name;
```

Your function should look like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (array_key_exists('content', $vars)) {
    $content = &$vars['content'];
      if (array_key_exists('field_photo_topic', $content)) {
      foreach ($content['field_photo_topic']['#items'] as $index => $info) {
        $tid = $info['tid'];
        $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
        $term_name = $term->name;
        $content['field_photo_topic'][$index]['#href'] = 'photos/' . $term_name;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that this will only work the way you intend if you use **PathAlias** or similar to alias the path to be accessible by  term name instead of numeric `$tid`.

Comment: Also, if your term names have capitals, spaces, or other characters that will make `photos/foo bar baz` "ugly", you may want to sanitize or otherwise clean it up.  If this is the case, I like to just use `pathauto_cleanstring()` from the pathauto module to do it.